# FritzBox: "fritz.box" resolving to strange .box url in Safari?

Tags: macos, iphone, safari

Trying to connect to our FritzBox through Safari (running Ventura 13.5), but (both) fritz.box (and http://fritz.box) is resolving to a strange site, see attached. iPhone is opening https://fritz.box as well. Friends mbPro is correctly opening the fritz-interface as expected.

Any ideas what's happening here?

EDIT: Cache is deleted completely, of course — I think.

[image: strange redirect?]

Comment: https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7430/1_Opening-the-FRITZ-Box-user-interface/

Comment: @Tetsujin Thx! Doesn't clarify why being redirected to said page with a completely cleared browser cache in my Safari. Other Browsers don't.

Comment: I can't test as I don't have a fritzbox, but it says to enter the full address… which is http not https, which *may* avoid it being handed off to DNS. It doesn't seem very smart at all, though, to be using a name that is a valid gTLD name without actually owning it themselves. It looks like someone has availed themselves of the opportunity & is now waiting patiently for Fritz to buy it off them. Beware, though, in the meantime it could be set as a phishing site pretending to actually be Fritz. I wouldn't use the domain name at all, I'd always use the actual IP address. That's safer.

Comment: See https://tld-list.com/launch-schedule and https://icannwiki.org/.box

Comment: https://www.heise.de/news/Verwirrend-Internet-Domain-fritz-box-zeigt-NFT-Galerie-statt-Router-Verwaltung-9610149.html (In german, but easily translatable in the browser).

Comment: Perfect, thx all! Really appreciate it.